# Why am I seeing a difference in WSL diskdrive list vs registry

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, wsl2

I'm trying to understand how WSL2 is interacting with the host Win11 operating system.

WSL diskdrive list brief reports my USB thumbdrive as `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2` and my internal SSD as `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0`

But in regedit `HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\Scsi Port 0\ Scsi Bus 0\Target ID 0\Logical Unit Id 0\DeviceName` says my SSD is `PhysicalDrive2`

Any idea why the discrepancy ?

Comment: Please provide the complete command you're running and its entire output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the registry is reporting a `DeviceName` for your drive (or what may have generated that propery).  In general, it appears the `HARDWARE` section of the registry is fairly undocumented.  And, as you can see, that's *not* the actual name you need to use for mounting anyway.

For reference, I have three SSD's in my system, and none have a `DeviceName` in the SCSI section.  For example:

```
> Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\Scsi Port 5\Scsi Bus 0\Target Id 0\'


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\Scsi Port 5\Scsi Bus 0\Target Id 0

Name                           Property
----                           --------
Logical Unit Id 0              InquiryData          : {0, 0, 6, 18...}
                               SerialNumber         : xxxx-xxxxx-xxx
                               Identifier           : NVMe    Samsung SSD 950 BXX7
                               DeviceType           : DiskPeripheral
                               DeviceIdentifierPage : {0, 131, 0, 24...}
```

It may be that a previous Windows release, or some other software, set this at some point on your system.  Even if that name in the registry is valid, it likely applies to *that* particular SCSI bus/port, and not the system as a whole.

But regardless, the SCSI Bus registry isn't the source of the names you need to use for WSL mounting.  That's returned by WMI (via CIM).  As you can see in [this article](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2012/04/09/how-obtain-the-source-of-the-wmi-data/):

> from where this data is obtained?. Well the answer is, this data is obtained from many sources like the WinApi, the Windows Registry, the SMBIOS or custom functions embedded inside of the MOF definition.

So we can't necessarily expect that you will be able to get the drive information directly from the Registry alone.  Also from that article, there is apparently a way to determine how WMI is retrieving those values, but I haven't dived into that Delphi code to see how it might be mapped to PowerShell.  The equivalent PowerShell article seems to have been taken offline by Microsoft, probably since WMI has been superseded by CMI in PowerShell.

As the [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) say, continue to use ...

```
GET-CimInstance -query "SELECT * from Win32_DiskDrive"
```

... to get the proper name to use with `wsl --mount`.  Also note that these *do* seem to map to the same "Disk numbers" you would see in *Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management*.

Comment: thanks!   I was hoping I could find something in the registry that could map a device in Enum\USB or something to the PhysicalDrive number.  Guess I'll have to dig into the Delphi code creator to try and figure that out.

Comment: looking at some other systems, none of them have a DeviceName value for any of the HKLM:\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\...  devices, so this was a wild goose chase...

However, I did find that Microsoft-Windows-StorageSpaces-Driver/Operational eventID 207 contains a DeviceNumber that matches the \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE number from Get-CimInstance, and it also contains the DriveID  {GUID} and the drive serial number, which was what I was ultimately looking for.

Comment: Good to hear you found it :-).  You should self-answer, at least, to close out the question.

Answer (score 0):

looking at some other systems, none of them have a DeviceName value for any of the HKLM:\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi... devices, so this was a wild goose chase...

However, I did find that Microsoft-Windows-StorageSpaces-Driver/Operational eventID 207 contains a DeviceNumber that matches the \.\PHYSICALDRIVE number from Get-CimInstance, and it also contains the DriveID {GUID} and the drive serial number, which was what I was ultimately looking for